# javascript window.open() and search the DOM in new window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to open a window with JavaScript then search this window for a specific string.

I cannot use an element ID or Class.

So I need to search the entire DOM in the window.

is this possible and if so how is it done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're opening a window to a URL with the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) as the page calling `window.open()`, then `window.open()` will return a reference to the new window. You can then use, e.g., jQuery to search the window with `$(".someCSSClass", newWindow.document)`.

If the URL you're opening is not in the same origin as the initiating page, then you won't be able to access its contents at all, and it will be impossible to do what you're asking.

Rule of thumb: if you're opening up a page on your own website, you can search it; if you're opening up a window on somebody else's website, you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you, I can rule that option out